# Chart.js in react native project not working at the moment

Tags: react-native, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

I am trying to do as followed the documentation from Charts.js to add a Line chart. I am literraly coppying the code from the exaple [here](https://react-chartjs-2.js.org/examples/line-chart/), but my project return with

**"view config getter callback for component 'canvas' must be a function (received 'undefined'). Make sure to start component names with a capital letter"**

I alredy check the files, the importations, but nothing is working out.

```
import React from "react";
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
} from "chart.js";
import { Line } from "react-chartjs-2";
import { Faker, de, de_CH } from "@faker-js/faker";
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native";

ChartJS.register(
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend
);

export const faker = new Faker({
  locale: [de_CH, de],
});

export const options = {
  responsive: true,
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      position: "top" as const,
    },
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: "Chart.js Line Chart",
    },
  },
};

const labels = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"];

export const data = {
  labels,
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "Dataset 1",
      data: labels.map(() => faker.number.int({ min: -1000, max: 1000 })),
      borderColor: "rgb(255, 99, 132)",
      backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)",
    },
    {
      label: "Dataset 2",
      data: labels.map(() => {
        console.log(faker.number.int({ min: -1000, max: 1000 }));
        return faker.number.int({ min: -1000, max: 1000 });
      }),
      borderColor: "rgb(53, 162, 235)",
      backgroundColor: "rgba(53, 162, 235, 0.5)",
    },
  ],
};

export function ContractChart2() {
  return (
      <Line options={options} data={data} ></Line>

  );
}
```

my code is looking like this. The diference from my code and the example is that i have fixed the Faker to work as intended. Anyone know how to fix this?

- importation validtion
- using the same example that is runing live om their site

Comment: React native can't translate canvas drawing (on which chart.js is based) to native graphics. You could theoretically use chart.js in a WebView, which isn't so "native" anymore. You may look up react-native-canvas.